# Data is not passing into SQL Server when using MVC Partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a popup dialog inside the partial view.  When a user clicks "Create" button, a popup dialog is shown, inside the popup dialog is a form where user types information and the information is then save into the database.  I got everything working and didn't get any errors but the data I typed didn't get saved into the database.

Please help, I am new to programming, Thank you.

Index page:

```
 <li>@Html.Partial("_Create")</li>
```

In my **_Create** partial view, I scaffolded the partial view using the **Create** template

> @model test.Models.Question
>
> ```
> <li><a href="#" class="create-question">Create</a></li>
>
> <div class="dialog-form-create-question" title="Create a question">
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm())
> {
>     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
>
>     <div class="form-horizontal">
>         
>         @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>         <div class="form-group">
>             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
>             <div class="col-md-11">
>                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
>                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <div class="form-group">
>              <div class="col-md-offset-8">
>             <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
>              </div>
>          </div>
>     </div>
> }
> </div>
> ```

My JQuery scripts for the form dialog nested inside the partial view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".dialog-form-create-question").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 510,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    });
    $('.create-question').click(function () {
        $('.dialog-form-create-question').dialog("open");
    });
    $('.cancel-button').click(function () {
        $('.dialog-form-create-question').dialog("close");
    });
});
```

In my Home controller, I changed the ActionResult Create(from scaffolding) to _Create:

```
        // GET: Home/Create
        public ActionResult _Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Home/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult _Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title")] Question question)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Questions.Add(question);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(question);
        }
```

Comment: are you able to get the model values in your _create(post) method ? please can put a break point and check.?

Comment: I put the breakpoint at public ActionResult _Create(httpPost) and it didn't hit.  I am not sure if I need to use Ajax for the popup dialog form inside the partial view.

Comment: try the below answer, I have changed your form, adding the action name , controller name and the FormMethod. Also added a submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try changing

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
}
```

to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_Create","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-11">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and see that your debugger strikes to _Create (post) method in your home controller with the values